# Scene loads 7 seconds later in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen

This line executes after 7 seconds, all the time. When I select the restart button, the scene loads after 7 seconds have passed.

```
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/4+10, Screen.height/4+2*Screen.height/10+10, Screen.width/2-20, Screen.height/10), "RESTART"))
{
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel); //works 7 sec later
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean it takes 7 seconds before the scene is loaded? If so, that can be pretty normal. Especially if you have a big scene. Next time please format your code, and proper English wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

two reasons for this .. your code which loads objects on scene or something is taking a long time are you relying on resources.load/playerprefs too much or something ?
 or you just have a really big scene... 
hmm one thing you can do if you have objects that are needed in two scenes or more don't create two objects just don't destroy the objects on load

Comment: Yes, my scene is really big. I guess I should reduce my scene. Thanks @Aodai Irshed !